# Can I connect a gatsby website with a salesforce product order system?

Tags: salesforce, gatsby

I have a client who needs a website for their restaurant done and I started work on it with Gatsby. I was however later informed that the client has a salsforce backend through which they offer functionality in which users can make an order online.

Now my questions is, is Gatsby still a good framework to work with? Will I run into any issues integrating salesforce into the website? Im a little worried as I know gatsby is famous for being a great static site generator and I could not find any evidence of anyone who has connected a salesforce backend to gatsbty

Your input is most valuable!

Answer (score 1):

Should be totally fine! Gatsby is great for anything that is updated infrequently or only has a small amount of it that is updated. I think Gatsby is an awesome choice for making the restaurant a site especially since things like Salesforce or 3rd parties may even offer a widget/iframe for directly interfacing with their ordering system.

TLDR: If most of your assets are static, Gatsby is a great choice especially for freelance web devs/small businesses like stores/restaurants as it just only gives you the JavaScript you need to stay active (event listeners, etc) and compiles everything else into fast HTML5.

Comment: thanks mate. I was worried I might have trouble fetching data and intergrating things like auth and making orders. Have you integrated salesforce with gatsby by any chance?

Comment: I haven't but have friends who have! Auth and Event Listeners are totally cool with Gatsby, depedning on how much you want to implement them. If you're building a site that's VERY stateful I'd avoid Gatsby but just for a few elements I think you're golden. Have you checked out the GatsbyNYC Slack or any of the other Gatsby slacks? I find them useful for finding people with a specific skillset!

Comment: Thats good to hear mate. Could you by any chance link me to these slacks? Im based in Poland and haven't got much knowledge of the web dev environ in NYC :)

Comment: https://join.slack.com/t/gatsbynyc/shared_invite/zt-ff7vz0nm-12bqJxG63AdBVMEp6naUQA

Here's one!

Comment: Thanks, bud! @Nicholas Feitel